# How can i take the real part of a complex matrix in breeze

Tags: scala, matrix, scala-breeze

I would like to take the real part of a breeze matrix. I try this as for complex number but it doesn't compile :

```
val realMat = mat.real
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mat.mapValues(_.real)` should do the trick

Answer (score -1):

A simple google search (3 seconds) could have led you to this:

```
val (er, ei, _) = eig(a)
```

Taken from here:
https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet